# Subsample size - when is it too small?

Tags: sample-size

I ran into a problem (question) with biological data analysis and don't know how to solve it. Will try to explain problem as simple as possible:

---

**Dummy example:**

There are 10000 textbooks in a library;
There are 1000 physics textbooks (10% of all the books);
I noticed that some of the physics textbooks have naughty drawings made by students;
Made a hypothesis that physics textbooks are enriched in naughty drawings, hence I did a permutation test (randomly resampled all the books in the library (10000) and got p value ~ 0). Indeed, physics textbooks are enriched in naughty drawings.
However, only 10 physics textbooks have those naughty drawings (0.1% of all the books in the library).
**Question:**
Is this subsample (0.1% of all the books) rational enough (statistically valid) to continue my analysis and draw conclusions about those naughty drawings physics textbooks (what field are those books from (e.g., molecular, optical physics), year of publication, etc.)?

---

**Actual problem:**

There are 10000 genes in a genome;
My sample is 1000 genes (they are responsible for embryo development);
I noticed that some of those genes (10) have specific characteristic (sequence that is responsible for [protein binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_binding_site));
Did permutation test (randomly selected genes from all the genes in a genome) and got p value ~ 0. This lets my state that genes that are responsible for embryo development are enriched in specific characteristic compared to all the other genes in a genome.
Is it worth continuing to analyze those 10 genes? My sample is 1000 genes and this subsample is only 10 genes? Is this enough to draw any conclusions about biology when their are 10000 genes in a genome?

Comment: All those 1000 genes are responsible for embryo development, but only 10 of them have specific characteristic?
I would be also concerned about the correlation among those 1000 genes (e.g correcting p.values for multiple testing).

Comment: Once you start an analysis based on an observation such as the one you report, all assumptions about probability distributions of test stastistics are off. You would have to conditionalize the test to classes where you stop your search for an interesting relationship by using the criterion you implemented... If there is no a priori hypothesis as to which genes are rlevant, you will have to take the search process into account...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of numbers of cases, remember that counts typically have a sampling error related to the square root of the number of counts. Thus your 10 binding sites in 1000 developmental genes essentially is considered as few as 6 or so for statistical comparisons, and your permutation-test comparison against the rest of the genome would have had to give you very high confidence that fewer than 0.6% of genes overall have that binding site. For a 10000-gene genome, that would mean high confidence that there are fewer than 60 total binding sites genome-wide, so presumably you found well under 50 binding sites outside of the developmental genes--maybe as few as 20 or 30.

So, if your permutation-test results are correct, the biologist in me says that you should go on to identify all of the genes that have the binding site, and not limit yourself to the developmental genes. The number appears to be few enough to study all of them systematically--particularly since your question seems to imply that you know the protein that binds to this site and you can thus approach the problem with modern molecular biological techniques. Such a highly specific DNA-binding protein/DNA site seems unusual to me and could either be very interesting or very boring; only physical experiments, rather than further statistical tests, are likely to distinguish those possibilities.